# Join all results from a one to many join in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, sql-server, one-to-many

I want to join all possible results (up to 5 counties intersect ZIP codes) from ZIP_County_Intersect to be populated as the null County fields in ZIP_County_Dissolve. These results are coming from ArcGIS Pro 3.1 but I don't know a quick way in GIS to get more than the first result from a one-to-many join added to the dissolve table. Is there a way to do this in GIS? I can also use SQL Server (SSMS).

Using the screenshots below as an example, I want the ZIP_County_Dissolve table to be updated so County1 = Sumter, County1_SqMiles = 4.46296251, County2 = Clarendon, County2_SqMiles = 62.52092399. Even better would be having the results ordered by largest SqMiles_ZIPparts so County1 = Clarendon, County1_SqMiles = 62.52092399, County2 = Sumter, County2_SqMiles = 4.46296251. How to do in SQL Server?

ZIP_County_Dissolve:
[image: ZIP_County_Dissolve]

ZIP_County_Intersect:
[image: ZIP_County_Intersect]

Comment: Have you investigated if the [Transpose Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/transpose-fields.htm) geoprocessing tool helps at all?

Comment: A similar tool I use is the [Pivot table tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/pivot-table.htm).

Comment: I have tried both of these, but am struggling to get them to do what I need.

Comment: Edit your question to explain (in detail) how you attempted to use these tools, and what went wrong, or where you got stuck.